# Using regex pattern stocked in file

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm working on a simple Python script which looks if any lines of an input file match any of the patterns from a CSV file.

The following code doesn't show anything:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import re
import csv

csvfile = open('errors.csv', 'r')
errorsreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")


log = open('gcc.log', 'r')

for line in log:
    for row in errorsreader:
        matchObj = re.match(row[0],line)
        if matchObj:
            print (line)
```

While the same code, with the following pattern instead of `row[0]` works:

```
.* error: expected ‘;’ before ‘}’ token  .*
```

I have been looking for workarounds but none of them seem to work. Any guesses?

Comment: csvfile is for reading lines like "1, 'a,b'" where the delimiter between fields also appears, quoted, in fields. Put your patterns in (for instance) patterns.txt with one pattern per line. Then read them in with "patterns = list(open('patterns.txt'))" and iterato with "for pattern in patterns:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that at first line from log you will read all lines from errorsreader and then you will read nothing. You can change

```
errorsreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t")
```

to

```
errorsreader = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="\t"))
```